# Group results under data names with sapply function and plot in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data which involves 3 separate data. Here is my data;

```
data<-structure(list(x = structure(list(value = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 6L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), y = structure(list(value = c(2, 2.1, 4, 3, 0, 1.2, 4.2, 
3, 4, 9)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), z = structure(list(value = c(1, 2, 7, 6, 0.3, 5.4, 4, 
3, 6, 7)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"))
```

And here is my sample function;

```
sam<-function(x) {
  ex<-c(3,2,4,5,2)
  z<-data.frame(x)
  y<-as.matrix(sapply(z, as.numeric)) 
  h<-lapply(c(2,5,10),  function(xx) tapply(y, as.integer(gl(nrow(x), xx, nrow(x)) ), FUN = sum))
  names(h)<-c("min2", "min5", "min10")
  min2<-h[[1]]
  pdf("plots.pdf")
  plot(min2, ex, main="min. compare",
       xlab="Historical Values ", ylab="Disaggregated Values", pch=19, col = "blue")

  dev.off()
  return(h)
}
```

In the function, I am aggregating values as shown. And then plotting `min2` with `ex` data.

With the code below, I tried to use the function for all data like;

```
v1<-sapply(data, sam)
```

But I can not see calculation's name as `min2` `min5` `min10` in result list. And also results are coming complexly, not under the `x`, `y` and `z`

I desire these two;

1) Grouping results under each data name. Like;

```
[x]              [y]            [z]
min2            min2           min2 
min5            min5           min5
min10           min10          min10
```

2) Plotting the desired ones for all `x`, `y` and `z`  as mentioned above. And export three plots to one pdf or separately.

Comment: I do not understand well what is your expected output. For 1), have you tried `v1<-sapply(data, sam, USE.NAMES=TRUE)`?

Comment: @iago Still I am getting same result. Output is aggregated values. For example, if we have 1-minute data, I am aggregating them to 2-minute, 5-minute and 10-minute data

Comment: `lapply(data, sam)` returns it in the original list format

Comment: Do you get the data output you need? To make the plot, you need to create the pdf outside the loop.

Comment: @StupidWolf Yes. So should I save pdf separately for each plot?

Comment: remove pdf("plots.pdf") and dev.off() from your function sam. Then do pdf("plot.pdf"); lapply(data, sam) ; dev.off()

Comment: This gives you 1 pdf, 3 pages

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks, this worked. I guess I wanted too much things. But is it possible to add text to each plot. For example, in my main function correlation coefficient is calculated. Can I write cor values for each data, to anywhere in the plot?

Comment: See below, a bit too long to write in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output, like @JonnyPhelps suggested, use lapply instead of sapply. To make the plots and get correlation you need to alter the function:

```
sam<-function(x) {
  ex<-c(3,2,4,5,2)
  z<-data.frame(x)
  y<-as.matrix(sapply(z, as.numeric)) 
  h<-lapply(c(2,5,10),  function(xx) tapply(y, as.integer(gl(nrow(x), xx, nrow(x)) ), FUN = sum))
  names(h)<-c("min2", "min5", "min10")
  min2<-h[[1]]
  plot(min2, ex, main="min. compare",
       xlab="Historical Values ", ylab="Disaggregated Values",
pch=19, col = "blue")
COR = cor.test(min2,ex)
LABEL = paste("cor=",signif(COR$estimate,3),"\np=",signif(COR$p.value,3))
mtext(LABEL,side=3,padj=2)
  return(h)
}
```

The correlation is calculated and you use mtext to place it at the top of the plot. You can play around with padj and adj to get the text where you need.

In your previous function, you called the plot in the function, this overwrites the file with every iteration. To plot all on a pdf, you need to do:

```
pdf("plots.pdf")
v1<-lapply(data, sam)
dev.off()
```

Or if you want them on the same page:

```
pdf("plots.pdf",width=8,height=4)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
v1<-lapply(data, sam)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried the adding cor to plot part with my main function, I am getting this "Error in COR$estimate : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error.

Comment: Also add each data's name to plot I used this. names<-unique(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(data))). But I failed about adding this to paste function as a label.

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi, you get the first error because the cor.test failed. what do you mean by main function?

Comment: And for the second part, you need to lapply through the names of data

Comment: I mean, the function I used for my calculations. I used sam function as a sample but my own functions is way too long.

Comment: I tried lapply. But in the plot "character(0)" is written instead of names. I used   LABEL <-lapply(x, function(x) (paste(unique(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))))

Comment: Hi @HüsamettinTayşi, I understand it might be frustrating for you, but yeah I can only guess that there is some part in your main function that is not working, and as for the names, you need to think about what to loop through. Here in this question, lapply(data, sam), what happens if you do lapply(colnames(data), sam), maybe you have to modify sam, but it will work